# AWS S3 Inconsistently Provides CORS Headers

Tags: amazon-s3, cors

I'm using AWS S3 and I've configured my Bucket to use CORS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I'm requesting SVG images from the Bucket, in a client-side React application. I'm rendering them inline so the response needs to have CORS headers enabled. Sometimes this works, and sometimes it doesn't. I can't isolate exactly what is causing the issue. I was retrieving one image fine; then I uploaded a new image to the bucket, and that image, once downloaded, was giving me the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/.../example.svg. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I've tried adding `<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>` and `<ExposeHeader>ETAG</ExposeHeader>`, and clearing my cache with every change, to no effect. I'm confused. Why aren't the headers coming through?

Comment: Try this workaround, just to see if my theory is valid: set the object metadata (when you upload, or later in the console) to return `Cache-Control: no-cache` for the object.  Clear your browser cache, and test.  As strange as it sounds, I believe this is a design problem with S3 that I've seen before.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't always return CORs headers, it seems that you need to provide a origin header and you don't always do so.

To make it consistent and always return the CORs headers you need to add one lambda function:

```
'use strict';

// If the response lacks a Vary: header, fix it in a CloudFront Origin Response trigger.

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
    const headers = response.headers;

    if (!headers['vary'])
    {
        headers['vary'] = [
            { key: 'Vary', value: 'Access-Control-Request-Headers' },
            { key: 'Vary', value: 'Access-Control-Request-Method' },
            { key: 'Vary', value: 'Origin' },
        ];
    }
    callback(null, response);
};
```

See the full answer and more details here: https://serverfault.com/a/856948/46223